# SQL Server Error 15441 - Database is no longer enabled for subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, clr

When I add an assembly in SQL Server, I get the following error or when I execute a stored procedure linked to a CLR assembly:

> Error 15441 - Database is no longer enabled for subscriptions.

What is the problem ?

Thanks !

I have restarted the server, the services, searched for more information on the internet but I can't find anything.